# Odd behaviour of rowstamp column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is the use of the datatype `rowversion` in a table always reliable?

I have seen a problem in comparing a value to a column of this datatype (ie `select * from MyTable where tStamp > @value`) and on investigating this - I have found some odd results. I am not sure if this is my misunderstanding, or a bigger issue that means the datatype cannot be relied on.

In the database is a table (MyTable) and the tStamp column is a `rowversion` datatype in which the minimum value is 0x00000004355B68B7. There is a stored procedure which accepts as input a parameter of the type `rowversion`, but that in turn calls a procedure that uses an input parameter of data type `binary(8)`. So the first procedure is declared like

```
create procedure proc1 @inputTS rowversion
```

and the second is declared like

```
create procedure proc2 @inputTS binary(8)
```

I assumed initially that the problem I was seeing was due to the fact that the datatypes were different (when proc1 calls proc2 it passes the value @inputTS over to it). And when I changed proc2 to use `rowversion`, I got the expected results. But then I tried a number of tests and what I saw from those ... was odd.

If I use the value 0x0000000070000000:

```
declare @testRV rowversion = 0x0000000070000000

declare @testBin binary(8) = @testRV 

select * from MyTable where tStamp > @testRV -- First Query

select * from MyTable where tStamp > @testBin -- Second Query
```

I found that the first select returned no rows and the second returned all rows. They should both have returned all rows. If I changed the value to 0x000000006FFFFFFF or 0x0000000070000001, then both queries did return all rows.

If I use the value 0x0000000080000000 then both queries return no rows. Using this value - 0x0000000441CED675 - both returned rows but this value - 0x0000000481CED675 - neither returned rows. And then using this value - 0x0000000080000001 - the first query returned all rows, the second returned none

At one point I was thinking that internally, SQL was treating the values as 2 integers - ie 0x0000000080000000 was 0x00000000 and 0x80000000. Since that's one higher than the max int size and is treated as -2147483648, it looked like the problem was where the "lower" integer was being treated as a negative. But that doesn't explain the behaviour when using 0x0000000070000000 or 0x0000000080000001.

I have tried this on SQL Server versions from 2008 R2 to 2017 and got the same results each time.

Am I missing something about how `rowversion` can be used?

Comment: It's not clear if this is just a typo, but `0x000000007000000` has only 15 digits. It's equal to `0x0000000007000000`, not `0x0000000070000000`.

Comment: typo - all values should be 16 digits including that one. And with the "lowest" value in the table being higher than all the test values, all queries should return results. At least, that's what i expected

Comment: I find your results odd and hard to believe (casual attempts at reproducing them have failed), and more inclined to think they are the result of what is in `MyTable` at any given point in time (and how rows are being shuffled around as a result of updates) rather than any flaw in how `rowversion` works. Can you reproduce this with something other than `MyTable` that is guaranteed not to be used by anything but your queries (i.e., a table created for the occasion?)

Comment: The "two integers" theory is easily debunked, by the way -- `BINARY` comparisons are conceptually done by `memcmp()` (disclaimer: I don't know if SQL Server actually uses `memcmp()` internally), that is, bytes are compared in order until the first pair that does not match is found. This works for `BINARY` values of any size, so that (e.g.) `SELECT 1 WHERE 0x128172818278172817287114 > 0x128172818278172817287112` gives a result. No sign bits are involved.

Comment: MyTable is just an example name. I am comparing values in several tables in several databases where they have been in use long enough to generate timestamps of that magnitude. If @@DBTS is much lower than 0x0000000080000000 then it doesn't seem to happen (and obviously, that's 2 billion).

Multiple tables, multiple databases, multiple servers, multiple versions.

Comment: example below...

`/*
create table t(id int identity(1,1), rv binary(8))
insert t (rv) values (0x0000000441D168E5)
*/

declare @rv rowversion 
--set @rv = 0x0000000080000000 -- Neither gives result  
--set @rv = 0x0000000080000001 -- rowversion gives result    
set @rv = 0x0000000002000000 -- binary(8) gives result  

declare @b binary(8) = @rv  

select * from t where @rv >0 and rv > @rv  
select * from t where @b >0 and rv > @b  

select * from t where rv > @rv  
select * from t where rv > @b  `

Comment: Sorry - that's formatted horribly.. but it can be reproduced in a new table with one row. It seems related to checking that the value is > 0 as well as the column  is > value. If the > 0 is not used, it seems to be OK

Comment: .. so I think that answered my own question .. the > 0 is using an integer. It needs to be using convert(rowstamp, 0) or convert(binary(8), 0) rather than an integer

Comment: You are the victim of SQL Server's byzantine rules on type conversion -- because `INT` is [higher in the type hierarchy than `BINARY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) (which is at the bottom) comparing a `BINARY` value with an `INT` will cause the former to be converted, which will simply take the lower 4 bytes and reinterpret them as a signed integer. And yes, `CONVERT(INT, 0x0000000080000000)` is of course less than 0. Moral: implicit conversions suck, throw rocks at them. However, the issue you describe there is not in your question.

Comment: Note that comparing a `ROWVERSION` to see if it's `> 0` is never meaningful. Either use `NULL` and check for `IS NOT NULL`, or use a non-nullable column but then use `<> 0x0`, if you're using all-bits-zero as a special value. (Relying on the chronological order is also mostly safe since `@@DBTS` monotonically increases, but inequality seems more appropriate if you're comparing against one special terminator value. (Unless `>` gives you better optimizer estimates, but hey.)

Comment: I'm debugging someone else's code - I missed the >0 part ;)

But the comparison is not to the table, its checking to see if the input was 0, the input being defined as datatype rowversion. That is provided by the application UI which is basically using the proc to pull a delta from the database.

This was driving me nuts, so it's been helpful to "talk out loud" here... thanks!